# VueJS routing troubles

Tags: vue.js

recently I've decided to port some of my apps to Vue so I could learn the framework, but I kind of got stuck at something.. so basically after I login on a Login view I'm supposed to be rerouted to my home view, but when I log into my app, it stays on the Login view, it only works after I'm already logged in and I press the log in button. State in the store clearly changes, I can clearly see my navbar responding to changes. The home view of course works after I manually go the '/' path but that's not a good user experience is it..

I've deduced possible reasons to only one thing. The navguards. And I don't know how to find a workaround, I've spent too much time thinking about this and I could use a hand to point me in the right direction. Here are some snippets of the code :

Login Methods:

```
methods: {
...mapActions({
  signIn: 'signIn'
}),
handleSubmit() {
  const data = {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password,
  };
    this.signIn(data).then(() => {
      this.$router.push({path: '/'})
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
    })
},
```

Vuex actions:

```
   async signIn({dispatch},data) {
        const res = await axios.post("auth", data);
        dispatch('auth', res.data.token)
    },
    async auth({commit, state}, token) {
        
        if(token) {
            commit('token', token)
        }

        if(!state.token) {
            return
        }

        commit('token', token)
        
        try {
            const res = await axios.get('auth')
            commit('user', res.data)
        } catch (e) {
            commit('user', null)
            commit('token', null)
        }

    },
```

Relevant Vuex getter:

```
isAuth: (state) => {
        console.log({token: state.token, user: state.user})
        return state.token && state.user
    },
```

Router/Navguard :

```
{ 
    name: 'Home',
    path: '/', 
    component: Home,
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if(!store.getters['isAuth']){
            next({path: '/login'})
        }else {
            next()
        }
    } 
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `await`-ing also for the dispatch in the signIn function:

```
async signIn({dispatch},data) {
    const res = await axios.post("auth", data);
    await dispatch('auth', res.data.token)
}
```

If you don't await the dispatch, then `user` might still be `null` when you call `this.$router.push({path: '/'})` and the route guard stops you from going to `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the issue related to Promise, the action `this.$router.push({path: '/'})` can be executed earlier than `axios.post("auth", data);`, I usually solve this problem by handling in the method:

```
handleSubmit() {
  const data = {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password,
  };
    const res = await this.signIn(data)
    if (res?.response.status === 200) { // change to the valid condition when success
      this.$router.push({path: '/'})
    }
},
```

and then in vuex action, you must return the response as well

```
    async signIn({dispatch},data) {
        const res = await axios.post("auth", data);
        dispatch('auth', res.data.token)
        return res;
    }
```

also, just in case the problem is not rendering the correct component, you should check your `<router-view ..`, add `key` props to make sure it's rerendered correctly, for the example:

```
<router-view :key="route.path" />
```